# Change between two given bases in a vector space of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

[image]

Did i do the 1st one correct?
Having difficulty understanding 2...1 step at a time just want to know if i did 1 correct

Comment: im almost done with number 2, i think i get it, just want to make sure i got 1 right...

Comment: or is it B= 1 1 1, 1 -1 0, 1 0 -1
 and for C = 1 1 0 , -1 1 1, -1 1 1 which way is the right way to do this?

Comment: I really dont want to re post the question because people will complain but i dont understand why no one can tell me YES or NO...if i did it RIGHT or WRONG...if WRONG then is the SECOND method CORRECT that i posted?

Comment: you need to show that $B$ and $C$ are linearly independent.. where did u show it???

Comment: what i want to know if i did the grid right... i posted in comment 2, the other form of the grid...I AM NOT SURE WHICH TO USE...thats all I AM ASKING... 
they are Linearly INDEPENDENT...

Comment: Please stop yelling.

Answer (score 1):

you need to show that both $B$ and $C$ are linearly independent. For this all you need to do is :$$c_1(t+t^2)+c_2(2t^2-1)+c_3(1+2t-t^2)=0$$

$$\implies t^2(c_1+2c_2-c_3)+t(c_1+2c_3)+(c_3-c_2)=0$$

Since this must hold for any $t$, we have $$c_1+2c_2=c_3$$ $$c_1+2c_3=0$$ $$c_3=c_2$$.

From here by solving you will get $c_1=c_2=c_3=0$. We can also do like you did.

The coefficient matrix will be $$\ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 2 & -1 \\
1 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 1 & -1 \end{array} \right)\ $$

The determinant is $1(0-2)-1(-2+1)=-2+1=-1 \ne 0$.Note that I evaluated along the first column. Since the determinant is non-zero, the solution possible is trivial.

Similarly you can proceed for $C$.

For(ii), $1-t-t^2=t^2(c_1+2c_2-c_3)+t(c_1+2c_3)+(c_3- c_2)$ which gives $c_1+2c_2-c_3=-1$, $c_1+2c_3=-1$ and $c_3-c_2=1$. Solving these will give you $\left(c_1,c_2,c_3\right)$. Similarly by solving $1+2t+t^2=t^2(d_1+2d_2-d_3)+t(d_1+2d_3)+(d_3-d_2)$, you will get $\left(d_1,d_2,d_3\right)$. Lastly by solving $2t+t^2=t^2(e_1+2e_2-e_3)+t(e_1+2e_3)+(e_3-e_2)$, you will  $\left(e_1,e_2,e_3\right)$. So the asnwer to your second question will be

$$\ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
c_1 & d_1 & e_1 \\
c_2 & d_2 & e_2 \\
c_3 & d_3 & e_3\end{array} \right)\ $$.

For (iii), $$q(t)=1-t-t^2+2+4t+2t^2+2t+t^2=2t^2+5t+3$$. Then all you need to do is find $a_1$, $a_2$ and $a_3$ such that $2t^2+5t+3=a_1(t+t^2)+a_2(2t^2-1)+a_3(1+2t-t^2)$. The answer will be

$$\ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a_1  \\
a_2  \\
a_3 \end{array} \right)\ $$.

Comment: The determinant is 1(0−2)−1(−2+1)=−2+1=−1≠0
where did the numbers in () come from?

Comment: I evaluated along the first column

Comment: do u mean u found the determinant?

Comment: y es.. I found the determinant and it came out be non zero. So the solution to $AX=0$ is $X=0$. As $A$ is invertible, we can multiply $A^{-1}$ on both sides to get $X=0$ which is what I did there

Comment: i dont understand your ending 2t2+5t+3=a1(t+t2)+a2(2t2−1)+a3(1+2t−t2). Not sure what u mean

Comment: since you need to find the coordinates of $q(t)$ with respect to basis $B$, you need to find $a_1$, $a_2$ and $a_3$

Comment: for C i got Grid  -1 1 1, -1 2 2, 1 1 0
then i did what u did -1(0-2)-1(0-1) = 2+1=3... is this correct for C?

Comment: and then i am not sure what u did or what to do...i am stuck at this point, not sure how to get a1, a2, a3 as u said...trying to figure out from this book...

Comment: any chance u can finish at least B so i can do C...i cant continue to part 2 or 3 cause im stuck on this...

Comment: I already solved $B$. '